# Recursive equation Of Euler's Backward PID With Derivative Filter

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform, transfer-function

I'm doing the implementation of the PID with derivative filter using the Euler's backward method, but I got stuck in this part since I have z in the denominator of most terms.

I didn't realize yet how I could get the inverse transform to obtain the recursive equation for the uC. Does anyone see any solution or can give me any advice?

Where:

K: is the proportional gain

Ti: Integrative constant

Td: Derivative constant

N: Derivative filter constant

[image: PID]
[image]

Just to be more specific: my doubt is how to get the inverse transform of a term like this:

\begin{align}
&&&\frac{N\cdot T_d}{z(N\cdot h + T_d) - T_d}(z^2)\\
\end{align}

That $z$ in the denominator is driving nuts, because if I hadn't that term I could just do

\begin{align}
u(k) = &&&\frac{N\cdot T_d}{(N\cdot h + T_d) - T_d}e(k+2)\\
\end{align}

Comment: I'll try to answer tonight. But usually we don't implement the PID as a transfer function even though it is. If you want to implement anti-windup, it is much easier to treat the integrator separately.

Comment: Hey, your notiation is a bit unclear. What is capital $Z$ and small $z$? is it really different? When you write things like $Ti$, what's that? Where does the $d$ factor used all over come from?

Comment: I tried to put what what I got from your equation into a $\LaTeX$ equation within your question, but I don't know whether that represents what you're actually doing. Please check, and fix if necessary!

Comment: Opss! My bad, thank you so much!! I'll rewrite everything to get in this final expression

Comment: Thank you so much, @MarcusMüller I clarified the problem. Those are the PID constants.

Comment: ah, is it possible that you mean some constants $T_i$ and $T_d$ when you write $Ti$ and $Td$?

Comment: @MarcusMüller exactly!

Comment: @Ben Never mind the 'transfer function' in the title, I'm sleepless for a few nights solving problems like this. What I mean is: Recursive equation  ‍♂️

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132399/discussion-between-bruno-santos-and-marcus-muller).

Answer (score 1):

Your second real mistake happens when you multiply both sides of the equation by $z - 1$.  This is both unnecessary and it makes the resulting problem difficult to solve.

Instead, start two equations up.  Here it is with the normalization of each term modified a bit so it'll be convenient later:
$$U(z) = K\left[ 1 + \frac{h}{T_i}\frac{z}{z - 1} + \frac{N\,T_d}{N\,h+T_d}\frac{z-1}{z - \frac{T_d}{N\,h + T_d}}\right] E(z) \tag 1$$

I am *not* going to work the coefficients out for you, but if you persist in your approach, you want to find $U(z)$ in the form

$$U(z) = \frac{b_0 + z^{-1}b_1 + z^{-2}b_2}{1 + z^{-1}a_1 + z^{-2}a_2} E(z). \tag 2$$

Now multiply both sides by the *entire* denominator:

$$\left (1 + z^{-1}a_1 + z^{-2}a_2 \right) U(z) = \left( b_0 + z^{-1}b_1 + z^{-2}b_2 \right) E(z). \tag 3$$

You ought to be able to take the inverse $z$ transform of this by inspection:

$$u[n] + a_1\ u[n - 1] + a_2\ u[n-2] = b_0\ e[n] + b_1\ e[n-1] + b_2\ e[n-2] \tag 4$$

Now solve that for $u[n]$, and you have your difference equation.  Or find a discussion of the various types of direct-form filters and choose the one that's best for you.

But your **first** real mistake is implementing a PID controller as a second-order generic filter.  The two big reasons this is a mistake is because, one, you can run into problems with the integrator pole not staying right at $z = 1$ because of coefficient precision, two, there's no easy way to turn a stage (like the integrator or the proportional gain) off, and third, you should **always** implement integrator anti-windup any time you have an integrator inside a control loop.

What you want to do is recast (1) as

$$U(z) = \left [ k_p + k_i\frac{z}{z - 1} + k_d\frac{z-1}{z - d_d}\right] E(z) \tag 1$$

(In your code, if you want to use the traditional form that's specified by $T_i$, $T_d$, $N$ and $K$, then just convert from those to the gains above -- I find it's easier to tune using the gains directly).

Then implement the proportional, integral, and derivative *separately* in your code, and add them up at the end.  If you have your generic PID controller and you find that you don't need integral action -- set $k_i$ to zero.  Ditto, if you find you don't need derivative action* you set $k_d$ to zero.

As part of this, *implement integrator anti-windup*.  This answer is getting pretty long, and you didn't ask -- so just do a web search on that term.  The short reason is that actuators saturate, integrator anti-windup is a good way to compensate for that, and there's a *ton* of different ways to implement anti-windup, each of which is best in some particular way -- so it's good to know a lot of them so that you can pick the best for any given control loop.

* This is pretty common -- derivative action can be problematic, you only want to use it if you must.